Reloading MVC5 Partial View that contains a Document Viewer
I have a partial view in MVC5 that displays a document viewer and a button that lets users upload a document.
I want to be able to reload the contents of the partial view or just reload the entire partial view itself when a document is uploaded so the document that the user uploaded would be visible as soon as they finish uploading it.
Here is the Document Viewer:
@{
    ViewBag.Title = ViewBag.PageTitle;
    Layout = null;
}

@using GleamTech.AspNet.Mvc;
@using GleamTech.DocumentUltimate;
@using GleamTech.DocumentUltimate.AspNet;
@using GleamTech.DocumentUltimate.AspNet.UI;

<!DOCTYPE html>
@{
    var documentViewer = new DocumentViewer
    {
        Width = 800,
        Height = 600,
        Document = @ViewBag.documentFile
    };
}
<html>
<head>
    @this.RenderHead(documentViewer)
</head>
<body>
    @this.RenderBody(documentViewer)
</body>
</html>

Here is what calls the document viewer:
        public ActionResult ViewSanctionDocument(long id)
        {
            var lstData = EmployeeMemoServices.GetEmployeeMemo(_usrInfo, id);
            string filePath = "";
            if (lstData.EmployeeDocImg != null)
            {
                filePath = Server.MapPath(lstData.EmployeeDocImg.Substring(3, lstData.EmployeeDocImg.Length - 3).ToString());
            }
            ViewBag.documentFile = filePath;
            return View();
        }

This is the display:
@if (Model.EmployeeDocImg != null)
                                {
                                    @Html.Action("ViewSanctionDocument", "TransactionSanction", new { id = @Model.Id })
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    <div class="dt-center justify-content-center col-md-12">
                                        <img class="rounded-lg figure-img img-fluid col-md-8" id="empimgPreview" src="../../Images/no-image.jpg" />
                                    </div>
                                }
                            </div>

This is what triggers the upload and is also where i plan to trigger the reloading of the partial view:
    $('#btnEmpSancSave').change(function () {
                    var empNo = $(this).attr('bId')
                    var data = new FormData();
                    var files = $(this).get(0).files;

            if (files.length > 0) {
                        data.append("MikeImages", files[0]);
                        data.append("EmployeeId", empNo);
                    }

                    $.ajax({
                        url: '@Url.Action(actionName: "SanctionDocumentSavingImage", controllerName: "TransactionSanction")',
                        type: "POST",
                        processData: false,
                        contentType: false,
                        data: data,
                        done: function (data) {
                            $("#viewid").html(data); //test
                        },
                        complete: function () {
                            alert('test'); //test
                        }
                    });
    });

So far I've tried doing a bunch of the things I saw it in here but none of them work.

Looks like you are trying to reload the partial view after uploading a document.
In your Controller, you can return a PartialView instead of a View:
public PartialViewResult ViewSanctionDocument(long id)
{
    var lstData = EmployeeMemoServices.GetEmployeeMemo(_usrInfo, id);
    string filePath = "";
    if (lstData.EmployeeDocImg != null)
    {
        filePath = Server.MapPath(lstData.EmployeeDocImg.Substring(3, lstData.EmployeeDocImg.Length - 3).ToString());
    }
    ViewBag.documentFile = filePath;
    return PartialView("_DocumentViewer");
}

In your main View where the partial view is displayed, you can use a div tag to load the partial view:
<div id="documentViewerPartial">
    @Html.Action("ViewSanctionDocument", "TransactionSanction", new { id = @Model.Id })
</div>

Then, in your jQuery code for uploading the document, after the upload is successful, you can reload the partial view like this:
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("SanctionDocumentSavingImage", "TransactionSanction")',
    type: 'POST',
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    data: data,
    success: function (response) {
        $("#documentViewerPartial").load(location.href + " #documentViewerPartial");
    }
});

